# Android Localization from resources

Tags: android, string, localization, resources

I am currently trying to localize my android app and i have setup everything but it keeps of loading the same string resource whenever i try to change the language.

I have the below **string resources**

```
values
values-am
values-om

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
String languageLocale = sharedPreferences.getString("SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE", "am");

    Log.d(TAG,languageLocale);

    String languageToLoad  = languageLocale; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I am also using the code below for selecting the language in a different activity

```
RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener =
        new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)mRadioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
                int checkedIndex = mRadioGroup.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);
                //AppController languageSetting = (AppController)getApplication();
                SavePreferences(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, checkedIndex);
                mLanguageId = checkedIndex + 1;
                languageSetting.setLanguageId(mLanguageId);
                switch (mLanguageId){
                    case 1:
                        SavePreferencesLocale(KEY_SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE,"en");
                        mTest = "en";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        SavePreferencesLocale(KEY_SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE,"am");
                        mTest = "am";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        SavePreferencesLocale(KEY_SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE,"om");
                        mTest = "om";
                        break;
                }

            }};
```

Now the problem is whenever the application started for the first time it loads the correct string resource but when I change the language it keeps the same string resource. that means eg. if the app starts with the values-am string resource when i change it to values-om i still see the values-am strings despite the locale is assigned with the correct value ("om")

Comment: By "keeps the same string resource" - you mean it didn't update current values in views to localized ones?

Comment: @aelimill Yes that is what i meant.

Comment: You need to manually update all the needed views or call recreate() in activity. Sadly, but this is the only way i know to make it works automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the below code on every language selection in `onCheckedChanged()`.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("Selected language code comes here");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

After setting the Locale, use `recreate()` to restart the activity.

Comment: I have tried that but still no luck. below is the change I made

Comment: I fixed the problem by clearing the cache and killing the process of the application. in other words i have to launch the app manually again. I feel my solution is not perfect and I think there is still a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something:

```
String languageLocale = sharedPreferences.getString("SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE", "am");
```

by **

> sharedPreferences.getString(""SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE", "am");

** you dont need string **"am"**. This **"am"** you need only by **.putString()**!

Should look like

```
  String languageLocale = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY_SAVED_LANGUAGE_LOCALE");
```

Comment: I am using that to access what I have saved in my shared preference. and I have tested it using the Log.d(TAG,languageLocale) and it was giving me exactly what I need. the string "am" is simply a default value

Comment: Where is putString()?

Comment: If you see in my first post the function SavePreferencesLocale() is called `private void SavePreferencesLocale(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Intent Refresh and call

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale); 
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
config.locale = locale; getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 

this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_category_page);
```